# Is it possible to only get a url title without load whole wabpage?

Tags: ios

I know that use a `UIWebview` can get title in delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad`

But,I want to know if there is a way to only get the title without load the whole webpage?Like http request or something else?

Comment: there are several more delegates like - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; or - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView; you can use them

Comment: I know this,I want to find a way without using uiwebview

Comment: The simplest way would be to read the html and parse string, similar to the answer you got, but simple `NSString` substring can do the work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create url request with asynchronous call to get data from url.

This can be done like this for example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
     // Get Title
     NSString *strTitle = @"";
     if (data && !err)
     {
         NSString *returnDataIntoString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         //NSLog(@"data : %@",returnDataIntoString);
         
         if (returnDataIntoString.length > 0)
         {
             NSError *error = nil;
             GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithHTMLString:returnDataIntoString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
             if (doc && !error) {
                 NSArray *employees = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//title" error:NULL];
                 for (GDataXMLElement *employe in employees) {
                     strTitle = [employe stringValue];
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Error : %@",[err description]);
     }
     
     //Set Title here
     
 }];
```

#### Note : Now i have used third party library to parse html using [GDataXML-HTML](https://github.com/graetzer/GDataXML-HTML)

Comment: Why can't this work because i know as you down voted my answer then you may be having alternate solution right so please provide that also??

Comment: I did not down vote your answer,someone else did it.I want to find a way to only get title so that I can save network flow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a whole HTML string? You can using regular expression to parse string if you have it:

```
NSString *string = @"Your HTML String";
NSError  *error  = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>"
                              options:0
                              error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSRange titleRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *title = [string substringWithRange:titleRange];
```

Comment: But in this way,I still need to download the whole string first.

Comment: Yes, If you do not request to the server, how do you get the title?

Comment: I mean make a request to server,and server return the title.

Comment: I think that make a request using `HEAD` HTTPMethod will save network flow, If the server returns title in the response header.